# VBA code for selecting a certain range from a specific worksheet, table, and clumn

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I am trying to select a variable range from a worksheet, from a specific table, and a specific column to clean the data. But I am having trouble specifying the range. Not sure if my code is wrong.
Select is already defined.

This is what I tried, but I remain to get an error.

```
Set rSelection = Worksheets("Warehouse Movement").ListObjects("WM_Data").ListColumns("StockCode").Select
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

`Select` doesn't return anything ... try

```
Set rSelection = Worksheets("Warehouse Movement").ListObjects("WM_Data").ListColumns("StockCode")
rSelection.Range.Select
```

... assuming you have correctly defined `rSelection` as a `ListColumn` and that each of your Worksheet, ListObject and ListColumns, as named, exist.

Comment: It gives the error "Run-time error '424": Object required"

Comment: Have you removed the `.Select` from the end of the first line? And what type have you 'Dimmed' `rSelection` as?